# What is the performance difference between chaining logical operators vs Array.prototype.indexOf

Tags: javascript

Recently I came across a situation where I had to do something if the value of a variable was one of a few values. I initially used chaining logical operators as follow:

```
function myFunction(value) {
  // ...
  if (value == 'one' || value == 'two') {
    // do something situationally
  }
  // ...
}
```

As the checks increased, I replaced the chained logical operators with indexOf call of an array to check if it exists in that array as following:

```
var checkArray = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
function myFunction(value) {
  // ...
  if (checkArray.indexOf(value) > -1) {
    // do something situationally
  }
  // ...
}
```

I was wondering if there is a performance difference between the two cases. As I can still manage chained logical operators, I can switch back to them if they are significantly faster.

Comment: Although it doesn't answer the question, it probably is important here: "premature optimization is the root of all evil" - Donald Knuth. Is the performance difference here in any way relevant to the project?

Comment: @ASDFGerte beat me to it. I doubt the difference is in any way significant for any real world purpose. Aslo, [relevant XKCD](https://xkcd.com/1691/)

Comment: Most likely the array approach is 100 times slower than using the operators, but ... who is interested in a difference of 0.001 msec / 100 ..?

Comment: You can probably use a switch instead of an array and indexOf

Comment: In my opinion you should go with second approach because its maintainable and if you got different and more value like `four, five ....` in future you have to make very less change if we compare with first approach

Answer (score 4):

For large numbers of options to test against, both operations will have the same computational complexity - `O(N)`. Every possible option needs to be checked in a loop (either inlined with `||`, or in the array where `indexOf` is checked on).

If you want `O(1)` computational complexity, and you have a *very large* number of options to test against, use a `Set` instead - `Set.has` is much faster when there are many items to check:

```
const sitautionalValuesSet = new Set(['one', 'two', 'three']);
function myFunction(value) {
  // ...
  if (sitautionalValuesSet.has(value)) {
    // do something situationally
  }
  // ...
}
```

(that said, as comments have noted, this is a somewhat odd thing to optimize for - unless this particular section of code is actually taking up a lot of resources, which it probably isn't, there are very likely better areas to focus on - run a performance test, and identify and fix found bottlenecks instead)

Comment: There might be a [Bot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9515207/certainperformance) activated by StackOverflow to answer the Javascript related questions!!!!

Comment: I do agree with this. It is a very good practical advice. A Set will have sub-linear search speed, most likely `O(log n)` (though that's not guaranteed - specs only recommend sub-linear). However, to just ground this to the question asked - in OP's, I doubt there are so many options that a Set will help. I'm basing this on the fact that OP says a chained OR is also possible. If you have about 100 of those it would be basically unmaintainable and that's not even the point at which a Set will have a good performance benefit.

Comment: Also this makes the maintenance bit more easier IMO. It's cleaner to add more items to a `Set` than to write more conditions in an `if-statement`. This is easier to read and understand exactly what you are checking against. Even though this is not a performance optimization for me it's still a significant improvement in code quality.

Comment: @Leron eh, it depends. I've not actually ever seen a place that used more than 3-ish chained ORs. Maybe there were 4. At any rate, with that low amount, it should be easy to understand what is happening. And usually it's not even checking the same value but something like `if (isReady || isOperationForced || user == "Admin)`. I don't think I've ever encountered a situation where a chained OR can be cleanly replaced with an array/set. Moreover, when I have seen more than 3-4 logical operations, it's a mix of ORs and ANDs. Refactoring is usually to move them to a function or a variable.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference, but it's good to use `indexOf` for large amount of data.

```js
function myFunction1(value) {
  console.time('chaining');
  if (value == 'one' || value == 'two') {
    // do something situationally
    console.timeEnd('chaining');
  }
  // ...
}
myFunction1('one');


function myFunction2(value) {
  console.time('indexOf');
  var checkArray = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
  if (checkArray.indexOf(value) > -1) {
    // do something situationally
    console.timeEnd('indexOf');
  }
  // ...
}

myFunction2('one');
```

JFI: `includes` is faster than `indexOf`, you can see test [jsperf](https://jsperf.com/array-indexof-vs-includes)

Comment: You will need to change the function names. Only the indexOf timer is shown because it overwrites the chaining function before the function call.